# Can't rotate loaded SVG in p5js

Tags: svg, p5.js

I'm trying to load an external SVG with

I'm using p5js-svg with p5js and for the most part I don't have any issues, but I'm stuck trying to rotate a loaded SVG. I'm working with both the last versions of pj5s and the library (p5js v1.4.1 and p5js-svg v1.3.3).
Here is the code to reproduce:

```
function preload() {
  svgs = [
  loadSVG('/img/plantilla_01.svg'),
  loadSVG('/img/plantilla_02.svg'),
  loadSVG('/img/plantilla_03.svg')
]}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, SVG)
  noLoop()
  angleMode(DEGREES)
  imageMode(CENTER)
}

function draw() {
  let posX = 0
  let posY = 0
  let imagen
  for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    let giro = random(-90, 90)
    push()
      translate(width/2, height/2)
      rotate(giro)
      imagen = svgs[floor(random(0,3))]
      image(imagen, posX, posY, width/10, height/10)
      posX += width/10
      posY += height/10
    pop()
  }
  }
```

The loaded SVGs are Adobe Illustrator-produced, and there's no issue with loading and displaying them. Which can be the issue with the rotation?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a bug with transforms not being applied to `image()` with the `SVG` renderer and `loadSVG()` (and I see you've already raised an [issue on github](https://github.com/zenozeng/p5.js-svg/issues/221)).

One workaround could be using `loadImage()` instead of `loadSVG()`:

```js
function preload() {
  svgs = [
  loadImage('/img/plantilla_01.svg'),
  loadImage('/img/plantilla_02.svg'),
  loadImage('/img/plantilla_03.svg')
]}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, SVG)
  noLoop()
  angleMode(DEGREES)
  imageMode(CENTER)
}

function draw() {
  let posX = 0
  let posY = 0
  let imagen
  for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    let giro = random(-90, 90)
    push()
      translate(width/2, height/2)
      rotate(giro)
      imagen = svgs[floor(random(0,3))]
      image(imagen, posX, posY, width/10, height/10)
      posX += width/10
      posY += height/10
    pop()
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it works (so it's kinda answered) but it renders the SVG to pixels, so it defeats the purpose, because we can't save vector shapes anymore.

Comment: Had a hunch that would be the case. Unfortunately I won't have the time to investigate the fix the bug with the p5.svg library. If this is time critical, it might be worth checking out other JS svg libraries such as [svg.js](https://svgjs.dev/docs/3.0/), [SnapSVG](http://snapsvg.io/demos/), or there's a chance [paper.js](http://paperjs.org/features/) might be able to help with that as well. Worst case scenario, it should be possible to use vanilla JS to access loaded SVGs and using the DOM insert them into a main SVG and animate them.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and used Javascript to fix it. Note that inline CSS only worked in the browser.

```js
function addRotationHack(ele = "rect, circle, ellipse, line, polyline, polygon, path") {
    // select shapes in the SVG
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(ele);
    // loop through them
    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

        let deg = Math.random() * 360;

        // ❌ Works in the browser, but not Illustrator (doesn't support inline CSS(?))
        // elements[i].style.transform = `rotate(${deg}deg)`;

        // ✅ instead set the property directly
        elements[i].setAttribute("transform", `rotate(${deg})`);
    }
}

// ... then call in draw() after your image
image(imagen, posX, posY, width/10, height/10)
addRotationHack();
```